# How do I find the solution(s) to $\cos^2x=2-2\sin x$?

Tags: trigonometry

In the interval of $[0,2\pi)$, how do I find the solutions to $$\cos^2x=2-2\sin x$$
I know that $\cos^2x=1-\sin^2x$, but don't see how to advantageously use this.

Comment: Think about how you can express $\cos ^2 x$ in terms of $\sin ^2 x$.

Comment: Like 1-sin^2(x)

Comment: Exactly. That's it.

Answer (score 3):

We have $\cos^2 x \equiv 1-\sin^2 x$, so your equation reduces to $$1-\sin^2 x = 2 - 2 \sin x$$Re-arrange and let $u = \sin x$ to get $$u^2-2u + 1 = 0  \iff (u-1)^2 = 0$$

The above is a quadratic in $u$, which has only one solution $u=1$. Back-substitute to get $$\sin x = 1 \iff x = \frac{\pi}{2} + 2\pi n$$ where we let $n$ range over the integers. In your given interval, the single solution is $$x = \frac{\pi}{2}$$

Comment: Okay that makes a lot more sense, thanks!

Comment: No problem! :-)

Comment: @Stacy if this answered your question, mark it as accepted by clicking the green tick on the left. :-)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$$\cos^ 2 x + \sin ^2 x =1 \to \cos ^2 x = 1 - \sin ^2 x$$
$$1 - \sin ^2 x = 2 - 2 \sin x$$

Now re-arrange this as you would a function of the form $ax^2+bx+c$ to find the zeros:

$$\sin ^2 x - 2 \sin x + 1 =0$$